# Не видно часть папок на примонтированном USB-диске в Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, доступ, mount

Имеется внешний диск с файловой системой exFat, подключенный по USB к компу с Ubuntu Server 21.10.

Примонтировал диск в папку (`sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb`).

Команда `ls` показывает все файлы и папки, но доступна из них только часть. У недоступных папок стоят вот такие доступы `d---------`.

При попытке поменять владельца папки (`sudo chown myuser TestFolder`) получаю сообщение `chown: невозможно получить доступ к 'TestFolder': Нет такого файла или каталога`.
Новые, созданные на этом диске каталоги, доступны.

Раньше этот диск стоял в сетевом хранилище, доступ был по сети из винды. Все папки создавались одинаковым образом. Собственно, под винду и по сети все доступно, в Убунте почему-то только частично.

Как это поправить?

Comment: Может, подключите к Windows-системе и прогоните проверку диска на всякий случай?

Comment: exFat не поддерживает атрибуты владельца. [вот тут](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=233071) написано об этом. `cd TestFolder` работает же? А как примонтировать под обычным пользователем - написано [тут](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364657/how-can-i-create-an-exfat-partition-that-can-be-mounted-without-root)

Comment: `cd TestFolder` выдает такое же сообщение про то, что такого каталога не существует.

Comment: `sudo cd TestFolder`?

Comment: `sudo: cd: команда не найдена`